# Why are some play times glowing green?

Tags: nintendo-switch

If you add friends on the switch, you can see their playtimes for the games that they have. I have noticed that some of the playtimes show up as green rather than grey. It is not because I own the game. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers appear to go from grey to green if someone has played that game for 50+ hours.

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/6snxc3/does_anyone_know_what_the_green_text_means/):

> If you've played more than 50 hours, it turns green.